# Can I use Annotate in ggplot2 to fill my violin graph?

Tags: r, ggplot2, annotate, violin-plot

I made a violin graph using rtruncnorm and a set of data and annotated it. This is my plot code:

```
 ggplot(g) + 
      annotate(geom = "rect", xmin = -Inf , xmax = Inf , ymin = 0, ymax = 1, fill = "red", alpha= 0.4) +
      annotate(geom = "rect", xmin = -Inf , xmax = Inf , ymin = 1, ymax = max(g$PGR), fill = "green", alpha= 0.4) + 
      geom_violin(aes(x=1, y=PGR), fill=NA , color="darkred") + 
      geom_boxplot(aes(x=1, y=PGR) , width = 0.01) +
      theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
            axis.text.x=element_blank(),
            axis.ticks.x=element_blank())
```

and received this plot:
[Violin Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CqPa.png)

[image]

I want to use annotate to fill the shape made by the violin plot. So I only want the area inside the "violin" annotated. any suggestions? clues?

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: I see you have `fill=NA` within the violin. Have you tried changing this to a color you want?

Comment: @CephBirk This doesn't give me what I want, the fill is significant here! it can't be one color! If you check the attached image it's two colours! Thanks though :)

Comment: How do you want it filled then? I'm confused...

Comment: Can you also add an image of your current plot so we get a visual representation?